# C# Multithread database access for Firebird (.NET)

Tags: c#, multithreading, firebird, threadpool

I'd like to take advantage of multithreading when we write data from the database into our own objects. We are currently using Firebird and retrieving data using the "forward-only" reader FbDataReader.

We cycle through the records held in the FbDataReader and populate an object, adding the object to a List which is then used within the application. All this occurs in the Data Access Layer of our application.

Ideally, we would like to retrieve data from the database (in a FbDataReader) and then split the work of writing to objects (one per row) between threads. The problem I see is that the FbDataReader is forward only and different threads may cause the reader to step the next record before another thread is finished.

A solution might be to dump the FbDataReader into an indexed List, Array or Dictionary but this would come at a cost.

Does anyone have any ideas or are we just wasting our time looking to refactor this part of our code?

Answer (score 0):

If you can obtain large blocks of contiguous records that don't overlap, and assign a data reader object to each, then you can use a thread for each reader and get gains, provided the data source doesn't cause a bottle neck. You will basically be using multiple reader objects in place of intermediate storage.

e.g.

```
where ID >= 0 && ID < 10000   << block 1 for data reader instance 1
where ID >= 10000 && ID < 20000  << block 2 for data reader instance 2
where ID >= 20000 && ID < 30000  << block 3 for data reader instance 3
```

This example of three readers will allow you to instantiate three objects "simultaneously".

If you additionally use a [C# iterator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/65zzykke%28VS.80%29.aspx) wrapped around this entire process you might have a way to return all the objects as if they were a single collection without using any intermediate storage for the instances.

```
foreach ( object o in MyIterator() ) { ....
```

This would bring the objects back under the banner of being used from a single thread even though they were created on different threads. I'm just blue-skying this last part.

Comment: I understand that using a forward only cursor cannot go quicker than one row at a time. Thats why I suggested the intermediary step of assigning all the data to an indexed array, list or dictionary which could be split between threads.

Comment: Sorry about the lead-in rhetorical questions; they weren't intended to insult. It's just to give everybody else something to think about in general when visiting this thread.  You're right it's evident you understand the intermediary need.

Comment: So the question begs. How would you dump the FbDataReader into a List, Array or Dictionary quickly. It seems there is no way to speed up this process. Thanks for your input so far, its appreciated.

Comment: If you're reading the records simultaneously instead of sequentially then likely you're inserting them into the chosen collection more quickly too. I don't know how optimized the end result would be - you'd have to test to see how much gain there is.  Gain is dependent on factors like time to contruct the objects; whether the chosen collection is: thread safe, allows fast insert operations, etc. Although the iterator approach replaces the need for an intermediate collection, I suppose at some point you will have to collect them somewhere. My suggestion addresses potential way to collect faster

Answer (score 0):

You can try to create a new thread and create there a new database connection based on the existing connectionstring. 
In one thread you can proccess the even records (2,4,6 etc) and in the other thread the odd records (1,3,5 etc). 
However this will increase the complexity of your code.

For lenghty database operations I prefer to create a new database connection object to do the work in a seperate thread and display a progress to the user, so that the UI thread does not freeze and the application remains responsive.